# Which MySQL directories to back up using FTP

Tags: mysql, backup, ubuntu

My server has been hacked and I only have FTP access to recover my data before reinstalling the OS.

Which/where are the directories that needs to be backed up? Will MySQL be recovered back to its initial state if I were to copy these directories back to the freshly installed server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you FTP `/etc/my.cnf`, read it and look for

- [datadir](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir)
- [innodb_data_home_dir](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_data_home_dir) : If this is not set, ignore this.

For most MySQL installations, this would be `/var/lib/mysql`